# Jquery Fadein/FadeOut simultaneously

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How are you?
This is from a previous post and a solution was posted.

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var allBoxes = $("div.boxes").children("div");
  transitionBox(null, allBoxes.first());
});

function transitionBox(from, to) {
  function next() {
    var nextTo;
    if (to.is(":last-child")) {
      nextTo = to.closest(".boxes").children("div").first();
    } else {
      nextTo = to.next();
    }
    to.fadeIn(500, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        transitionBox(to, nextTo);
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
  if (from) {
    from.fadeOut(500, next);
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

[JSFIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/CYJLA/)

However I was trying to extend this a bit, where when box 1 fades out, you can see box 2 fading in slightly at the same time - simultaneously, and as box2 fades out ...box 3 is fading in at the same time with the opacity going from 0 to 1

Comment: you need to post the code in the question not just the jsfiddle link

Comment: Have you ever tried it on your own? maybe you should show us your code?

Comment: Yes I was messing with the duration value, but no success.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fine and you? :') .

I have a solution that maybe can help.
Have you tried making 1 class named display and setting `display: block;` and then put it on the function as `toggleClass()`. Finally you make a new class named as `.transition`(I do this with all my project to make them easier) and put it on the div or add it with some code like: `$("div").addClass("transition");`.

the code for `.transition` should be like this:

```
.transition {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

You can also try insted of CSS and jQuery using only CSS.
an example could be using CSS Animations. Define the class of every box and then make a animation and add a delay on every animation so it will show every certain time, make them infinite so the will loop.

Hope you understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Editing line 14 of your jsFiddle to add a delay created a smoother effect so you don't see two at once. Which I surmise is the answer to the question.

Line 14 edits: `to.delay(100).fadeIn(500, function () {`

Comment: Yes this transition is smoother, but I'm still not getting when one elemeting is fading out and is going to opacity 0, the other element should be fading in and already at opacity 0.5 on its way to 1.

In Order words- you will never see a full white background.